# "Incorrect decrement"  and "Potential leak" messages from Analyzer

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, static-analysis

When I compile with the analyzer, I get a couple of messages. I have these properties declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SyncServicePrimary *syncAndCartOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SyncServiceSecondary *syncAndCartTwo;
```

This method is called from `applicationDidBecomeActive` and I get "Potential leak of an object allocated".

```
-(void)makeTheCartObjectsForCountry:(NSString*)country_key{
    self.syncAndCartOne = [[SyncServicePrimary alloc] init];
    self.syncAndCartTwo = [[SyncServiceSecondary alloc] init];
}
```

This is called in `applicationWillResignActive`; here I get "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object".

```
-(void) removeTheCartObjects{
    [self.syncAndCartOne release];
    self.syncAndCartOne = Nil;    
    [self.syncAndCartTwo release];
    self.syncAndCartTwo = Nil; 
}
```

If I set the objects to `autorelease`, the error goes away, but I want the objects to be released when the app hides itself.

Is this something I am doing right but that is split too far for the analyzer to see the start and end, or is this something I can do better/properly so it won't complain?

Its more than likely that I am missing a simple concept with regard to `release` and `alloc` cycles (I've come from PHP and C#).

Comment: Note that `Nil` is the null literal for class pointers. For object pointers, you should use `nil` instead.

Comment: Just to drive it on home, if i am doing a nil check on an instance of a class; using an " == Nil" is not the same as "== nil" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
-(void)makeTheCartObjectsForCountry:(NSString*)country_key{
    self.syncAndCartOne = [[SyncServicePrimary alloc] init];
    self.syncAndCartTwo = [[SyncServiceSecondary alloc] init];
}
```

You're creating the objects and then retaining them (because of the property declaration), so they have a reference count of 2, when only one object is referencing them.

You should do it like this:

```
-(void)makeTheCartObjectsForCountry:(NSString*)country_key{
    SyncServicePrimary *primary = [[SyncServicePrimary alloc] init];
    self.syncAndCartOne = primary;
    [primary release];

    SyncServiceSecondary *secondary = [[SyncServiceSecondary alloc] init];
    self.syncAndCartTwo = secondary;
    [secondary release];
}
```

Comment: Autoreleasing everything just seems like a lazy practice to me. Sure, it's necessary sometimes, but it's always better to manage your memory directly.

Comment: And it is always better because…?

Comment: I'd like to avoid auto-releasing especially with these objects because they spawn multiple treads based on timers and nsnotifications, if i don't implicitly clear them i can't be 100% sure there wont be two threads accessing the same rest service

Comment: So just to note, in the case of autoreleased class methods and retained properties i can just leave them as is? e.g. `[self setTitleString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mystring]];`

Comment: @misterkoz You can leave them as is.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the properties with attribute `retain`, so the analyzer assumes that the setter method for the property looks like this:

```
- (void)setSyncAndCartOne:(SyncServicePrimary *)newValue
{
    [newValue retain];
    [self->_syncAndCartOne release]; // access the instance variable holding the property value
    self->_syncAndCartOne = newValue;
}
```

If you use `@synthesize`, the setter method will look like that.

So, when `makeTheCartObjectsForCountry:` returns, the object in `syncAndCartOne` has a retain count of 2, but should only have a retain count of 1.  That's why using `autorelease` fixes it.

You shouldn't be doing `[self.syncAndCartOne release]` for the same reason.  The setter method will send the old object a `release` when you assign `nil` to the property.

Comment: Awesome, so it looks like i'm double retaining and creating a redundant line with the = nil call. wish i could set two as the accepted answer...